# JQuery Not Loading on Wordpress Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a site that is using the Visual Composer plugin. Unfortunately from what I'm seeing, Jquery is not loading on the site. So what I did is I installed the WP jQuery Plus plugin to hopefully load the Jquery files for use, but that didn't work.

You can see an example of the site here: http://tinyurl.com/mqdy7wl

That page is supposed to be an accordion with content that drops down on the links. Not sure what to do at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: looking at the source, there is no jquery plugin loaded AND the page is just a part of the full code. Can't help you with only half the information

Comment: DoXick, check again. I loaded the full template.

Comment: jquery is being loaded, but can you disable WP jQuery Plus and upload that template again? it should work without that plugin, i guess (i dont have the composer plugin). I don't see jquery-ui loaded though, which is the library that handles the accordion stuff normally

Comment: Still no dice when the Load JQuery plugin is uninstalled. This is a head scratcher for sure.

Comment: the script for Visual Composer isn't loaded at all. Now i don't know how this is implemented, but i can't see it in the source. maybe post your header.php here to see how that looks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see the contents of your template file, but one thing to consider is whether your templates are correctly invoking `get_header()` and `get_footer()` in the appropriate locations (or, if you don't have those corresponding files available, then `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in lieu of those).

Also, you may not have enqueued the jQuery libraries you require; somewhere in your functions.php file or a similarly appropriate location you'll want to perform `enqueue_script` for the relevant libraries; consider the information in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-the-proper-way-to-enable-jquery-in-wordpress for reference.

Comment: The call for the header is in there. I'll take a look at the enqueue_script for the functions.php file in a few.

Answer (score 0):

I see a link to jQuery in the page header, and when I check the console jQuery appears to be loaded and working. Is this a question about `$` being `undefined` ? Wordpress loads jQuery in noconflict mode - [you can read more about it here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)